# How to check database for duplicates before inserting?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I would like to check the database for duplicates before inserting into the database. It is only considered a duplicate when plateNo, driverID and resDate match.

Here is how I get the data that will be inserted to the database

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        String client = (String) clientCmb.getSelectedItem();
        String[] cparts = client.split("-");
        String cpart = cparts[0];

        String driver = (String) driverCmb.getSelectedItem();
        String[] dparts = driver.split("-");
        String dpart = dparts[0];

        String van = (String) vanCmb.getSelectedItem();

        java.util.Date oDate = jXDatePicker2.getDate();
        DateFormat oDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String date = oDateFormat.format(oDate);
        model2.addRow(cpart, dpart, van, date);


    }
```

And here's the code for my addRow method

```
public void addRow(String client, String driver, String van, String res){

        try {
            String sqlRes =  "Select * from reservation";
            rs = st.executeQuery(sqlRes);
            rs.moveToInsertRow();

            rs.updateString("clientID", client);
            rs.updateString("plateNo", van);
            rs.updateString("driverID", driver);
            rs.updateString("resDate", res);
            rs.insertRow();
            rs.moveToCurrentRow();
            rs = st.executeQuery(sqlRes);
            this.fireTableDataChanged();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyModel2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Comment: You can use select count(*) from some_tbl where plateNo = v1 and driverId =v2 and resDate = v3. If the result is equal to 1 (=1) then you should not insert.

Comment: Which database engine?

Comment: @Y.B. I'm using Mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the database do the work for you.  Define a unique index/constraint specifying that those three values are unique in the table:

```
create unique index unq_reservation_3 on reservation(plateNo, driverID, resDate);
```

If you attempt to insert a duplicate -- or do an `update` that results in a duplicate -- then the database will return an error.  You simply need to catch the error.

Comment: this worked like a charm! However, by simply changing the driverID or the plateNo, it will insert the data. How do I prevent a client from adding another reservation on the same day?

Comment: Add even more constraints! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use `MERGE` statement: [T-SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) or [ORACLE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9016.htm), or for MySQL:

```
PreparedStatement p = con.prepareStatement("
    INSERT INTO reservation tgt (clientID, plateNo, driverID, resDate)
    SELECT (? As clientID, ? As plateNo, ? As driverID, ? As resDate)
    FROM DUAL ins
    LEFT JOIN reservation ref
        ON  ref.resDate = ins.resDate
       AND (ref.plateNo = ins.plateNo OR ref.driverID = ins.driverID)
    WHERE ref.clientID IS NULL;
");
p.setString(1, client);
p.setString(2, van);
p.setString(3, driver);
p.setString(4, res);
return p.executeUpdate(); /* 1 - Success | 0 - Ignored Duplicate */
```